# Application failed 2 times due to AM Container

Tags: apache-spark, emr

Hi All,

I am running a Spark job written in JAVA which is processing an Eexcel file and writing the output as a JSON string.

The Excel file to be processed is kept in S3. I am running the job on Amazon EMR.

The result should be a JSON string

But i am getting the following error

```
diagnostics: Application application_1513081568718_0001 failed 2 times due to AM Container for app
attempt_1513081568718_0001_000002 exited with  exitCode: 10
For more detailed output, check application tracking page:http://ip-172-31-76-243.ec2.internal:8088/cluster/app/application_1513081568718_0001Then, click on links to logs of each attempt.
Diagnostics: Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_1513081568718_0001_02_000001
Exit code: 10
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: The error that you’ve posted simply says that the yarn application failed. This could be for many reasons. Can you post the container logs (per the instructions in the message you posted)?

Comment: Hi Ed , This is another question how to acess the container logs.      it throws an error if i try to acces the logs via the url http://ip-172-31-76-243.ec2.internal:8088/cluster/app/application_1513081568718_0001  on my windows machine from where I connect to EMR

Comment: `yarn application -status application_1513081568718_0001` and `yarn logs -applicationId application_1513081568718_0001` should help

Comment: where do i have to run this command specifically?

Comment: hI philantrovert,                                                                                           do I have to run the command on the Master node or the slave node of the EMR cluster.

Comment: star73 it doesn't matter where the command is run.

Comment: Ok thanks for the info Ed